# Set text to appear on the top, in a large table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like this;

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>mytext</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table tr td{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

which look like this;

[image]

But I want the text to start at the beginning of the box, like;

[image: Expected]

How can I achieve this? **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VSZZJ/)** is the working fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/VSZZJ/2/

```
table tr td{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `vertical-align: top`

Update fiddle here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VSZZJ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your css.

```
table tr td{vertical-align: top;}
```